# How to use for loop to get value from db with multiple variable?

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite

I need to use for loop get values from database to show in multiple variables
What should i do? help me please.

My Variables :

```
var printerName1: String = ""
var printerName2: String = ""
var printerName3: String = ""
var printerName4: String = ""
var printerName5: String = ""
```

My Function :

```
func load(){

    var selectPrinter = [printerName1,printerName2,printerName3
     ,printerName4,printerName5]

    let db = SQLiteDB.shared
    db.openDB()
    let data = db.query(sql: "select * from tbPrinter")
    for index in 0..<data.count {
        let row = data[index]
        if let printerName = row["name"]{
            selectPrinter[index] = printerName as? String //Cannot to set value in variables
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set the text value of the textfield by index you should add them to an array and then you can use the same index of the resultset to set the text.

```
let printers = [
    printerName1, 
    printerName2, 
    printerName3, 
    printerName4, 
    printerName5
]

func load() {
    let db = SQLiteDB.shared
    db.openDB()
    let data = db.query(sql: "SELECT * FROM tbPrinter")
    for index in 0..<data.count {
        let row = data[index]
        if let printerName = row["name"] {
            printers[index].text = printerName as? String
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How to if I switched to use the variables instead of outlets